# R: If condition followed by several commands

Tags: r, if-statement, command

I have a if-condition which is followed by several commands. However, there seems to be a syntax error and it is not working. I guess this is pretty easy. I searched around for correct docting but didnt find a solution. Thanks for your help!

```
#data
supply_by_gas <- rep(0,365)
supply_by_gas[] <- 32069547/365
overall_gas_prod <- 51224298

#here the condition which should be true
if (overall_gas_prod > sum(supply_by_gas))
#followed by two commands
{peak_use_gas <- (overall_gas_prod - sum(supply_by_gas))
overall_gas_prod <- sum(supply_by_gas)-1 }
else
{peak_use_gas <- 0}
```

that's the error I receive:

```
Unexpected 'else' in "else" 
> {peak_use_gas <- 0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (overall_gas_prod > sum(supply_by_gas)) {
    peak_use_gas <- (overall_gas_prod - sum(supply_by_gas))
overall_gas_prod <- sum(supply_by_gas)-1 
} else  {
peak_use_gas <- 0
}
```

Comment: thanks! i already tried that but it always gives me: Error: Unexpected 'else' in "else"
> {peak_use_gas <- 0}

Comment: Do it just like that including line breaks and placement of curly brackets. You are just placing the curly brackets incorrectly

Comment: In particular, check out the second sentence of the second paragraph of the **Details** section of `?"if"`

Comment: wow, did not expect that this matters. Thanks!

Comment: It matters more at the console.

Comment: @BenBarnes - while I remember reading that paragraph many moons ago, it seems a little disappointing that the documentation doesn't actually include an if-then-else example. I suppose I should write one and submit it if it concerns me!